# Get data from sample page using jQuery AJAX method

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am given a sample page to obtain a string from it. The I am to convert this sting to a variable that can be used for a different code. I been trying for hours to get the data from the page but I am at a lost.

First I created a sample code to read the page and using the Chrome console I could see the word I needed to get. This is the sample code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loaddata").click(function(){ 
        $.post("http://www.assessmentnj.com/Services/MagicWord.asmx/GetMagicWord",function(data){
        console.log(data);
        datafromwebsite = data;
        magicWordResult = "Your word to guess is " + datafromwebsite;
        alert(magicWordResult);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Get the object from sample page:</div>
    <button id="loaddata">Load data</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I created a second code to get the string and create my variable, but I am not sure how to do this. I researched books and websites and I am not sure. Any suggestions? Thank you guys. Here is the code I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loaddata").click(function(){ 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.assessmentnj.com/Services/MagicWord.asmx/GetMagicWord",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Get the object from sample page:</div>
    <button id="loaddata">Load data</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ha ha :) When you're not sure, you have to try :D

Comment: do you get the data from the target page ?. do you see a log at console .

Comment: instead of `console.log(data);` write `datafromwebsite = data;` and the variable `datafromwebsite` will contain the external page's content

Comment: Here is where I am lost, because I make the change to the `success:function` but I am still not getting a result when I click on the button. Is it something wrong with my function?               `success:function(data){
                    datafromwebsite = data;
     magicWordResult = "Your word to guess is " + datafromwebsite;
     alert(magicWordResult);`

Comment: Are you sure it's JSON data that you're retrieving from the MagicWord page?

Comment: This is what we were told. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of `console.log(data)`, try `console.dir(data)` and see if you get a result in the console.  Also, is your server on the same domain as the MagicWord server? [assessmentnj.com]?

Comment: I do get a lot of information when I try `console.dir(data)`, but I don't see the string I need. As for the server, no I am not at the same server as the MagicWord server. I actually made a change to the code and instead of `json` I tried `xml` and this is what I get from the first code `Your word to guess is [object XMLDocument]`

Comment: First, copy and paste the results of "console.dir(data)" to your post. Then change dataType:"xml" to dataType:"html" and see what happens.

Comment: When I used `html` I get the whole code plus the string like this `?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">fish</string>`. How do I extract the word `fish` from this?

Comment: I posted the output from the `console.dir` as an answer, it was quite extensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.assessmentnj.com/Services/MagicWord.asmx/GetMagicWord",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

try

```
$.get('http://www.assessmentnj.com/Services/MagicWord.asmx/GetMagicWord', function(xml) {
    // this should contain your magic word
    console.log(xml.childNodes[0].innerHTML);
}, 'xml');
```

Comment: Ninja, this seems to do the trick. I can now print the word and use it as variable in the code. My questions is this, why would they ask us to use a `post` request, and that the data was `json`, but when do that it was not working.

Comment: If `POST` is really mandatory, you can leave it as-is, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/f819r4yj/. I only used `GET` because unless I'm sending something to the site, using `POST` seems unnecessary. The data type just can't be JSON since nothing seems to be returned when you do. Do they perhaps want you to return the data in JSON?

Comment: This does the work, but I have one issue [http://jsfiddle.net/gcardonav/kgheq3d0/](http://jsfiddle.net/gcardonav/kgheq3d0/). If you see this code and run it in a webpage you can see in the console that the word gets changed every time I click. How can I create a global variable outside the click method but that starts with the click method?

Comment: I actually figured it out. I needed to put the Ajax method before the click one, so it does not reset it and gets a new word.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the first jQuery script and the second is the fact that the second script specifies that the returning data is in JSON format.

You could actually have written the second script in "shorthand" form like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loaddata").click(function() { 
        $.getJSON("http://www.assessmentnj.com/Services/MagicWord.asmx/GetMagicWord", function(data) {
            console.dir(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Which is VERY similar to the first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the input from the `console.dir(log)`

```
URL: ""
activeElement: null
anchors: HTMLCollection[0]
applets: HTMLCollection[0]
baseURI: null
body: null
characterSet: null
charset: undefined
childElementCount: 1
childNodes: NodeList[1]
children: HTMLCollection[1]
compatMode: "CSS1Compat"
contentType: "application/xml"
cookie: [Exception: DOMException]
currentScript: nulldefaultCharset: undefined
defaultView: null
designMode: "off"
dir: ""
doctype: null
documentElement: string
documentURI: null
domain: ""
embeds: HTMLCollection[0]
firstChild: string
firstElementChild: string
fonts: FontFaceSet
forms: HTMLCollection[0]
head: nullhidden: true
images: HTMLCollection[0]
implementation: DOMImplementation
inputEncoding: nulllastChild: string
lastElementChild: string
lastModified: "09/07/2014 21:54:24"
links: HTMLCollection[0]
localName: null
location: null
namespaceURI: null
nextSibling: null
nodeName: "#document"
nodeType: 9
nodeValue: null
onabort: null
onautocomplete: null
onautocompleteerror: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpaste: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onpointerlockchange: null
onpointerlockerror: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreadystatechange: null
onreset: null
onresize: null
onscroll: null
onsearch: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onselectionchange: null
onselectstart: null
onshow: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
ontoggle: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwebkitpointerlockchange: null
onwebkitpointerlockerror: null
onwheel: null
ownerDocument: null
parentElement: null
parentNode: null
plugins: HTMLCollection[0]
pointerLockElement: null
preferredStylesheetSet: null
previousSibling: null
readyState: "interactive"
referrer: ""
rootElement: null
scripts: HTMLCollection[0]
selectedStylesheetSet: null
styleSheets: StyleSheetList
textContent: null
title: ""
visibilityState: "hidden"
webkitCurrentFullScreenElement: null
webkitFullScreenKeyboardInputAllowed: false
webkitFullscreenElement: null
webkitFullscreenEnabled: true
webkitHidden: true
webkitIsFullScreen: false
webkitPointerLockElement: null
webkitVisibilityState: "hidden"
xmlEncoding: "utf-8"
xmlStandalone: false
xmlVersion: "1.0"__proto__: XMLDocument
```